# Swift multiple #available checks for bug in 2 versions of SDK

Tags: swift, sdk, version

Apple had a bug in the SDK, which I needed to implement a workaround, they have since fixed that bug but not for two versions of the SDK. I would like the workaround to apply to just those two versions, but there does not seem to be a way of specifying that with `#available`. `#available's` intent is to check a version or later.

For example, there was a bug in 14.3 and 14.4, but that was fixed in 14.5, I would like the workaround to not be in effect after that. I came up with this, however, I am pretty sure that the second check is not going to work on 14.3. Is there a way to turn off the check after a version, or provide a range of versions? Also, you are not able to provide `||` or `&&` the #available `if` or `guard` statements.

```
guard #available(iOS 14.3, *), #available(iOS 14.4, *) else { return }
// work around code.
```

The best I can come up with is this, but that workaround will be there from 14.3 onward:

```
guard #available(iOS 14.3, *) else { return }
// work around code.
```

Comment: could you try to if-elseif block like: #available(iOS 14.4, *) else if #available(iOS 14.3, *) else #available(iOS 14.2, *) ... etc?

Comment: I think as soon as it sees the 14.3 or 14.4 it won't turn off for 14.5.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can think of is this:

```swift
if #available(iOS 14.5, *) {
} else if #available(iOS 14.3, *) {
    // workaround code
}
```

I know it's ugly, but it works. Unfortunately, Swift does not seem to provide a way to give a maximum value for `#available`.

Edit: A cleaner method, but one that does not use `#available`:

```swift
let versionNumber = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
guard versionNumber >= 14.3 && versionNumber < 14.5 else { return }
// workaround code
```

Edit 2: In Swift 5.6 (Xcode 13.3), you can do:

```swift
guard #available(iOS 14.3, *) else { return }
guard #unavailable(iOS 14.5) else { return }
// workaround code
```

Comment: Available and unavailable cannot be in the same statement @Bbrk24